# Why are we extending our number of digits by adding zeros to the left to complete the arithmetic operations?

Tags: arithmetic, computer-science, binary, decimal-expansion, binary-operations

**For the sake of subtraction, we used complements instead of subtracting, but we did we extend to 6 digits? And why 6 digits not 4 or 5?**

[image]

**ANSWERS:**

[image]

**General rule for arithmatics with complements:**

[image]

Comment: You must use a power of 10 that is larger than  your number.

Comment: fleablood: well 5 digits is bigger than my number, why did they use 6 instead of 5 ?

Comment: Because $9, 286+801$ will have 5 digits.  You can use 5 for b and c as they are subtraction and the result will have 4 digits.  But a and d will require 6 as the result will have 5 digits.

Comment: Note $10^n$ has $n+1$ digit.

Comment: makes sense... yet its not 100 % identical to what's written above in the general rule..

Comment: That helped a lot thank you :)

Comment: that general rule is for subtraction.  I'm sure the general rule for addition will comment upon this.

Comment: @fleablood 9286+801 = 10 087 and - 9286 - 801= -10 087 those are largest possible and they have 5 digits, Can we extend to 5 digits instead of 6 ? Thank you

Comment: What does "extend to 6 digits" mean to you? If these have 5 digits don't we have to extend to something bigger?

Comment: @fleablood hope I understood you: you mean we should extend to something bigger so 1 digit more than what can accommodate our max and min numbers, right? so here since we can be satisfied by 5 digits to accommodate 10 087 we'll extend to 6 digits. "extend to 6 digits" means to me the following: the 2's complement representation of the negative numbers will be made up of six digits